# Partial trace instead of trace in definition of entropy

Tags: quantum-state, entropy, linear-algebra

For a bipartite quantum state $\rho_{AB}$, we have that the von Neumann entropy is

$$S(\rho_{AB}) = -\text{Tr}(\rho_{AB}\log\rho_{AB})$$

If instead, one took the partial trace above and obtained

$$\rho'_A = -\text{Tr}_B((\rho_{AB}\log\rho_{AB}))$$

Is $\rho'_A$ an object that has been studied? Its trace gives us the entropy of $\rho_{AB}$ and it is positive semidefinite so I'm wondering if (up to normalization) it is related $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$ in some way?

Comment: @glS The spectral theorem tells you for any state $\rho$ (not general psd operator) we will have $-\rho \log \rho$ is psd. Therefore the partial trace should still be a psd operator as partial trace is a postive map.

Comment: The question is quite vague though. I mean if you take any pure state then $\rho \log \rho = 0$ and so it's completely independent of the marginal state.

Comment: @Rammus, yes you are right that it is a bit open-ended but I thought I'd ask since it seems to be the halfway point in going from the density matrix to the entropy. Thought it might be an interesting object :)